# How do I fix this Multires Modifier artifact?

Tags: artifacts, multiresolution

Edit: Solved on my own, see answer

I'm rigging and weight painting eyelids for animation on my creature and came across this artifact that appears present only on the right side. I've located the issue to be with the Multires Modifier because when I toggle the Viewport Display, it goes away. "Apply Base" did nothing. It is only visible while in Object Mode - the mesh in Edit Mode appears completely fine. What is causing this, and more importantly, how do I fix it? Thank you!

[image: Multires Modifier artifact with Viewport toggled On]

[image: Multires Modifier with Viewport toggled Off]

[image: Mesh in Edit Mode looking completely fine]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go into *Sculpt Mode* and simply use the *Smooth Brush* in that area. Solved some pinching in other parts too.